# jQuery gallery with additional sidebar description?

Tags: jquery, gallery

I am looking for a jQuery plugin or library that has the horizontal thumbnail browsing below the image being displayed along with a sidebar column that shows detail of the currently selected photo, such as description and so on.

It would be basically two columns with the left column consisting of the picture and horizontal thumbnail.

Ideally I would like to have something that makes all of these column positioning configurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like [this](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-5.html)?

It's kind of a pain to adjust the layout and doesn't shrink down that great but I've used this plugin in the past and it's easy enough to setup and runs well.

Comment: yes! this is very accurate to what I need, except it should fit the whole browser window instead of shrinked.

Comment: Sweet, it should be easy enough to make the width 100%. It just doesn't like to get smaller as easily. Glad to be able to help